# How to style PopupMenu and AlertDialog with theme.xml and style.xml

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles, popupmenu

I want to skin my Android App with multiple Color Themes.
This Guides/Tools helped me to generate the basic `theme.xml` and `style.xml`

- http://android-holo-colors.com
- http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator
- http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1240

But i cant figure it out to style the **PopupMenu** and **AlertDialog** Header?

I want to change only the Color to streamline with my App Theme!

Example:
[image: before, taken from: developer.android.com/images/ui/dialogs.png]

to look like
[image: after, taken from: developer.android.com/images/ui/dialog_custom.png]

I’m using `Theme.Holo` and Android SDK 21.1 RC3/Tools 16.0. I've tried a lot with styles and themes but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlertDialogThemed extends AlertDialog {
public AlertDialogThemed(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
    final int color = resources.getColor(R.color.dialog_color);

    final View title = findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"));
    if (title != null) {
        ((TextView) title).setTextColor(color);
    }

    final View titleDivider = findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android"));
    if (titleDivider != null) {
        titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
```

}